# Mockito EditText set and get value in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-edittext, mockito

I want to test my `validator` and it has a lot of method that accept `EditText` as a parameter. The problem is that I'm not able to set `EditText` text value correctly here's what I did

```
val emailTxt = mock(SpannableStringBuilder("test@gmail.com")::class.java)
`when`(emailField.text).thenReturn(emailTxt)

validator.checkEmail(emailField)
```

But here's the value that I get

```
mock for spannablestringbuilder, hashcode: 2069466373
```

instead of `test@gmail.com`

Other thing that I tried is

```
`when`(emailField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("test@gmail.com"))
```

However then I got this `java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getInstance in android.text.Editable$Factory not mocked` so anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to refactor so that you pass a `String` containing your `EditText`'s text, instead of the `EditText` itself to `validator.checkEmail()`. Validation logic shouldn't really depend on Android-specific code.

Comment: Actually my validator is responsible for edittext error message displaying and other Android related stuff. :)

Comment: And that's why you are having one hell of a time implementing tests ;)
Why are you using mockito in this case? Sounds like you should use espresso and do full on-device integration testing for your validator.